# Volume of Solid of Revolution (Glass)

Tags: integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

We are given $y^2/a^2-x^2/b^2=1$, $y>0$ . If we rotate the hyperbola around the $y$ axis the shape is similar to a glass.
[image: glass]

What will the volume of water inside the glass be, in order to fill the glass up to $y=A$, $A>a$?

Following the given hint I found
$$x=b*(y^2/a^2-1)^{1/2}.$$

Comment: Why don't you show your attempt? Otherwise we are not able  to help you.

Comment: See my hint below. Now you should know how to start.

Comment: Start by drawing a picture of the hyperbola. See where you have the intersection with $y=A$.

Comment: I have done this using geogebra, however I am not sure what my integral should be

Comment: Why don't you paste the picture (or a link to it) into your question? It would help us to reference it in our answers.

Comment: Also add a sketch of a shell that you want to integrate

Comment: What's the answer if you know?

Comment: I think it should be πb^2*(A^3/3a^2-A-a/3+a)

Comment: Correct! Also have a look at my method. It's fast...

Comment: I would use disks for this problem and not shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The green axis in your picture is the $y$ axis. You can calculate the volume in two ways: disks or shells.

The disks are perpendicular to the $y$ axis, have a thickness $dy$ and the radius is equal to $x$ at a given $y$. In this case your integration variable is $y$. So the volume of the disk is $\pi x^2 dy=b^2(y^2/a^2-1) dy$. You know the minimum $y$ is $a$, and the maximum is $A$.

The shell method means that you need to have cylindrical shells, with the axis parallel to the $y$ axis. The radius of the cylinder is $x$, the thickness is $dx$. The volume of the shell is then $2\pi x h(x)\mathrm dx$, where $h(x)$ is the height of the shell. The "bottom" of the shell starts at $y=a\sqrt{x^2/b^2+1}$, and the "top" is at $y=A$, so $h(x)=A-a\sqrt{x^2/b^2+1}$ The integration range starts from $0$ and goes on until the height is $0$, or $y(x)=A$.
$$\frac{A^2}{a^2}-\frac{x_{max}^2}{b^2}=1$$
You can now get the upper limit of $x$ from the above equation.

Comment: which integral should I use to calculate the volume?

Comment: Do both. Just to check that you get the same answer. Personally, I think the disk method is easier in this case. Integrating polynomials is easier that integrating functions with square roots.

Comment: In the disk method what should my integral be? I didint really get it

Comment: You integrate over $y$, between $a$ and $A$ the volume of the disk

Answer (score 1):

I do the problem in cylindrical coordinates as follows:
Converting the equation of hyperbola to hyperboloid around $z$ can be simply done by replacing $y\to z$ and $x\to r$ as: $$\frac{z^2}{a^2}-\frac{r^2}{b^2}=1$$
(I figured this by reconciling $r$ with $x$ in the $x-z$ plane)

Now the integral becomes terribly simple:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_a^A\int_0^{\sqrt{b^2(\frac{z^2}{a^2}-1)}} rdrdzd\theta=\pi b^2\int_a^A\Bigg(\frac{z^2}{a^2}-1\Bigg)dz=\pi b^2\Bigg(\frac{(A^3-a^3)}{3a^2}-(A-a)\Bigg)$$

Answer (score 0):

So in your drawing you show that you are almost near to find the good start.

Take half of the trapezoidal stripe you indicated,  going from the y axis to the hyperbola.

Its width is $dy$, one base is $x(y)$ and the other $x(y+dy)=x(y)+x'(y)dy$.

When you rotate it by $2\pi$ you get a conic frustum of height $dy$ and volume $\pi x(y)^2 dy$ because you know that higher order infinitesimal can be waived.

Then just integrate the above along $y$, between the bounds you need.